# Share photos from iPhoto to iOS devices on LAN without iCloud

Tags: macos, ios, photos.app, photos, home-sharing

I have an iMac running OSX 10.10 and iPhoto v9.6. I have multiple iOS devices, mostly running iOS 8. How can I let the iOS devices browse the photos on the iMac without physically storing the files on iCloud or some other cloud service? Is there a way to just serve my photos from iPhoto to other devices on the local area network?

Ideally, I'd like to achieve this without the use of third party apps. If this is not possible I'm more partial to installing thrid party apps on the iOS devices than on the iMac.

Answer (score 1):

[PhotoScope](http://photoscopeapp.com/) is a paid app available for iPad, iPhone and iPod touch that allows you to browse an iPhoto library on the local network without using iCloud or other services. It does, however, require a free helper app be installed on the Mac to enable this.

(Note that I have not used PhotoScope and therefore, YMMV.)